# If you want to get the conditional number of Childs in a firebase database, how to do it?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The caveat is they should be from today. Since timestamps are by definition a time point, you can also use them to limit the count to ones from today.

Below is what I came up with but still have an error at `var timestampDate`:(

> Use of undeclared type 'timeinterval'

Summary:

1. The count of timestamp Childs is what we want.
2. but only the ones with timestamp of today.

Code:

```
let uid1 = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
var today: Date = Date.init()
                let thisUserRef1 = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid1)
                let myPeopleRef1 = thisUserRef1.child("peopleWhoLike2")
      myPeopleRef1.observeSingleEvent(of:DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
              print(snapshot)
          var timestampDate: timeinterval = snapshot
          var otherDate: Date = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: timestampDate)
          let calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current
          let result = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: timestampDate, to: today)
          print("result.day")


                      let thisUserRef = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid1)
                      let myPeopleRef = thisUserRef.child("peopleWhoLike2")
        .queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue:result.day<1 )
            myPeopleRef.observeSingleEvent(of:DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
                      print(snapshot.childrenCount, "ooooo")
                 })

           })
```

Comment: When it comes to coding in most languages, casing matters. The correct type name is `TypeInterval`, not `typeinterval`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780353-init

Comment: do you mean TimeInterval not Type. It solves that issue, but then you get error: Cannot convert value of type 'DataSnapshot' to specified type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

Comment: That's because you're trying to convert the entire `DataSnapshot` instead of just its `value` property.

Comment: I see, so how do you get its value property?

Comment: `snapshot.value`. I highly recommend reading the Firebase documentation, which has a section on [listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events). You also could do worse than taking the [Firebase codelab for Swift developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/). A few hours spent there will save you much more time in the future.

Comment: I'll check those out. Thanks. Am a bit rusty. It's been a while

Comment: Does the rest of the code look error free at quick glance?

Comment: I am honestly not sure if the last few lines actually accomplish what is wanted. Hense I am not sure the question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't 
`var timestampDate: timeinterval = snapshot`

**timeinterval** need to be **TimeInterval**

i.e `var timestampDate: TimeInterval = snapshot`

TimeInterval is a type so you need to spell it with the proper upper-cases.

Comment: that's true thanks. My bad. But then you get error: Cannot convert value of type 'DataSnapshot' to specified type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')